# Getting delta of array values from constantly updating array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, ecmascript-5

Having a problem getting something which should be rather simple to work.
I am constantly updating an array with new values and as I do so I need to get the delta or difference between the lowest and highest values. The length of the array should remain constant at 10.
The problem is that only the 1st and last values of my delta array seem to change. What am I missing?

Although in AS3, should be almost identical in Java or Javascript

```
 private var _deltaArray:Array= new Array();

private function update(myVal:int):void{
  if (_deltaArray.length < 10) {
        _deltaArray.push(myVal);
    }   

 if (_deltaArray.length >= 10) {
    _deltaArray.push(myVal);
    var delta:int =getDelta(_deltaArray);
   _deltaArray.shift();
 }
}//end func

 private function getDelta(a:Array):int {
        var total:Number=0;
        var L:int=a.length
        if (L > 1) {

            a.sort(Array.NUMERIC);


            var delta:int=int(a[0]) - int(a[L - 1]);
            trace('getDelta delta= ' + delta);
        }
        return delta;
 }//end func
```

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you mean by your problem, but it seems odd that you're sorting the array and then `shift`ing it. `Array.sort()` will modify the original array, so you're always removing the smallest value. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.
I needed to clone my array BEFORE sorting it to retrieve delta value

Answer (score 0):

This is just a suggestion, but why not keep a running count of your delta? I can only code this in pseudo-code, but:

```
private double max = Double.MIN;
private double min = Double.MAX;

private void update(integer value) {
    array.push(value);
    max = value > max ? value : max;
    min = value < min ? value : min;
    if (array.length > 10) {
        array.shift();
    }
}

private int delta() { return max - min; }
```